# How can I set the default install location of a WIX bundle to a registry string if one exists?

Tags: wix, installation, burn

I have a WIX bundle that currently allows the user to change the default install directory. I would like to change the default install directory before the user has access to it to a string from the registry if it exists there.

Desired logic:

```
1. Set default directory (currently using '<Variable Name="InstallFolder"
     Type="string" Value="C:\Users\Public"/>')
2. Get string from registry entry (currently using '<util:RegistrySearch
     Id="InstallLocSearch" Variable="PrevInstallFolder" Root="HKLM"
     Key="SOFTWARE\Company\App\InstallDir" Result="value"/>')
3. If the registry entry contains a non-empty string, override InstallFolder
     with string, leave it alone otherwise (not sure what to do here)
4. Allow user to change install dir if desired (done in UI)
```

What I would like to do is use another Variable element to assign the PrevInstallFolder variable to InstallFolder after the registry search. But how would I make sure that that variable gets assigned after the registry search happens? Also, how can I assign it only if the registry string isn't empty?

There is another similar stack overflow entry that sort of addresses what I want. The difference is that it checks to see if a directory exists. I don't care about this, so the solution doesn't really apply.

Comment: What all did you try for this and where is your code? Please do not expect people to write the code for you. Write the code and if you come across an issue, post it here so that others can chime in and help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could code out that logic in a C# custom action.

In the function you could set your install folder property to whatever you want:

```
Session["INSTALLFOLDER"] = "C:\Yourdir\etc"
```

Then use the same property name in the Directory definition fragment.

```
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop"/>

      <Directory Id="Websites" Name ="Websites">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="It'll be as set in the CA">
          <Directory Id="SUB_DIR" Name="sub_dir">   </Directory>
```

Schedule your CA to run before CostFinalize.